# How to upload pdf file by caputring first page of the file?

Tags: jquery, pdf, upload

I want to know How to upload pdf file by caputring first page of the pdf file??

using jquery.

thank you.

Comment: Be more specific, put examples, show us your research until now. Read the FAQ. Thanks.

Comment: i am showing link of the course material in which it will open pdf file.But, i want to display image of the pdf file along with the link.The image should be first page of the pdf file which i am uploading

Comment: OK, now copy everything you put in the comment, and add it to the question, so you make a half decent question. Then, try one of these (I did not test any) http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pdf

Comment: Now you have to indicate what's your backend language, and make a deeper search on stackoverflow. You'll find something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606175/how-do-i-extract-image-from-a-pdf-file-using-php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract the first page using some server side technology and display this image in the page. The browser itself can't open the PDF without any plugin so don't expect jQuery to be of any help here...

Comment: ok i am using .net .so,can you help me how to do it for the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with jquery. You must upload the whole pdf and process it at server by extracting the page and sending back to client as an image.

Comment: ok i am using .net .so,can you help me how to do it for the above scenario.